# First and last methods being called when loading UIViewController with XIB

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to be able to track how much time my UIViewController takes to load - from start to finish.

What is the first method being called and what is the last when loading a UIViewController with an attached XIB?

Answer (score 0):

This is the life cycle of an UIIViewController, first method is `viewDidLoad` and the last one `viewDidUnload`

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCHy.jpg)
**[Edited - Link updated]** You can use `viewDidDisappear` instead `viewDidUnload`

Comment: I don't want to wait for the view to unload. Just to finish loading. The link leads to a 404 error :/.